# php Mysql avoid insert into duplicate entries

Tags: php, insert-into, no-duplicates

I have two tables names 'users' and 'bursary'.
I want to copy all the username into 'bursary' table from 'users' table with condition the user Department=Bursary
I want to avoid duplicate entries.

my code is ,

```
$query25 = "INSERT INTO bursary (UserName) 
SELECT users.UserName 
FROM users 
WHERE users.DepartCent='Bursar'";

$result25=mysql_query($query25);
```

I have tried but not working, can anyone help me on this? Please help me.

My user Tables look like this,

```
UserID    UserName     DepartCent

  1          a          bursary
  2          b          registar
  3          c          bursary
  4          d          bursary
```

I want to select all the UserName and InsertINTO table bursary where the DepartCent='bursary'

Comment: did you make your username column in bursary table 'unique'? try that first..

Comment: @Girish , where is my mistake? where and what should I edit?

Comment: @satish you can use group by condition to eliminate duplicate entry from table1 to table2

Comment: @MiyaG, can you guide me? Im just a new beginner to this pphp mysql

Comment: `INSERT INTO bursary (UserName) 
SELECT users.UserName 
FROM users 
WHERE users.DepartCent='Bursar' group by users.UserName`

Comment: If your example schema is correct, it looks like you have a typo in your code. Shouldn't it be `WHERE users.DepartCent='bursary'`

Comment: @AdiBradfield edited, but issue unsolved....

Answer (score 0):

On your select have you tried the 'unique' keyword?  Or is the issue adding names to the users table that are already on the user table.

Both are do-able, is this a one shot thing, or needs to be done often?

Comment: I already make UserName is bursary as unique keyword. But the issue is I want to select all the username in users which the column DepartCent='Bursary".

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by condition to eliminate duplicate entry from table1 to table2

```
INSERT INTO bursary (UserName) SELECT users.UserName FROM users WHERE users.DepartCent='Bursar' group by users.UserName
```

OR

You can use this one.

```
INSERT INTO bursary (UserName) SELECT distinct(users.UserName) FROM users WHERE users.DepartCent='Bursar'
```

Comment: Need i make the UserName in bursary table as 'unique'?

Comment: No there is no need to make bursary as unique. Because you are selecting unique data from `users` table that is group by `UserName`. Please try this query and test Is it perfect for you? If not then discuss here, will help you :)

Comment: Are you sure your bursary table is empty or it has data?

Comment: it has no data. just entering. but when run the 2nd time, it will add the duplicate data

Comment: Okay got it... see above updated answer which is delivered by me.

Comment: tried using INSERT INTO bursary 
    (UserName) SELECT distinct(users.UserName) FROM users WHERE     users.DepartCent='Bursar' 
but still the issue is unsolved :( :(

Comment: @satish this query `INSERT INTO bursary (UserName) SELECT distinct(users.UserName) FROM users WHERE users.DepartCent='Bursar'`  pick only distinct user not duplicate values from one table to another one. Try to find the issue in your logic what do you want and what is happening. If possible share piece of data of both tables.

Comment: There is no duplicate value is users table, the issue is when copy the username from users table to bursary table..... there is duplicate value in bursary username column.

Comment: @satish what is the output of below queries?  `SELECT count(users.UserName) FROM users WHERE DepartCent='Bursar' ;` and 
  `SELECT count(distinct(UserName)) FROM users WHERE DepartCent='Bursar' ;`

Comment: Its count the total number of username in the table users where DepartCent='Bursar' and display it in table bursary column = UserName

Comment: @satish Are you mad crazy? I think you don't want answer of your problem.?? What I am asking are you providing or not?

Comment: If i use
INSERT INTO bursary (UserName) SELECT count(distinct(UserName)) FROM users WHERE DepartCent='Bursar' 

its showing total number of Username's where DepartCent='Bursar'. its dilapying the number in bursary UserName column

Comment: @satish Bro you need to learn more about mysql. At this stage we can't help you with as you have not little bit knowledge of mysql

Comment: Also read my all comments carefully. Hope you will find out the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. but let me clear my problem with you. I have insert this query25 in the register form. next whenever customer register with a username with choosing department/center = busary, the username need to be enter in bursary table username too.

Comment: you can execute two queries simultaneously in both table at the time of registration .

Comment: yes. 1 is enter in users table, and another 1 is enter the username in bursary table where DepartCent='Bursar'.